# coredns pods getting failed created by kubeadm init command

Tags: kubernetes

When I run `kubeadm::init` command, all pods are running except coredns pods. when I describe the pods, its showing something `cni initialization failed`. 
do I need any network plugin to be installed before running `kubeadm::init`??

Comment: Are you *sure* you provided enough code, configuration informations, and reproducible steps for Stack Overflow users to be able to understand and/or reproduce the error you're facing?

Comment: You can install a network plugin after you ran `kubeadm init`. You cannot normally install it before that.

Answer (score 0):

No, the network add-on is only added after `kubeadm init`, the documentation is explicit on this topic: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network